# comparing two arrays of hashes and making changes to one based off of result[Ruby]

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have two arrays:

```
a = [{:name=>"John Doe", :number=>"555-234-5678", :count=>30}, {:name=>"Jane Doe", :number=>"555-456-1234", :count=>12}, {:name=>"Kobie Bryant", :number=>"555-621-9876", :count=>8}, {:name=>"JD", :number=>"555-234-5678", :count=>3}, {:name=>"KB", :number=>"555-621-9876", :count=>6}]

b = [{:name=>"JD", :number=>"555-234-5678", :count=>3}, {:name=>"KB", :number=>"555-621-9876", :count=>6}]
```

When the initials of a[:name] matches b[:name] and a[:number] matches b[:number], I want to add the sum of both counts to a[:count] and then delete any instances of the elements in b from the a array.

So the result of a would be:

```
a = [{:name=>"John Doe", :number=>"555-234-5678", :count=>33}, {:name=>"Jane Doe", :number=>"555-456-1234", :count=>12}, {:name=>"Kobie Bryant", :number=>"555-621-9876", :count=>14}]
```

So far, I have:

```
h = []
b.each do |double|
    a.each do |conn|
        if (double[:name][0,1] == conn[:name][0,1].split[0,1]) && (double[:name][1,1] == conn[:name][1,1].split[0,1])
            h[double] += conn[:count] + b[:count]
            a.delete(conn)
        end
    end
end
```

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks guys!

Comment: Check your `a` and `b` array again. output is not telling the exact logic. How `33` here `{:name=>"John Doe", :number=>"555-234-5678", :count=>33}` ?

Comment: John Doe's count = 30 + JD's count = 3. Since they both have the same number, John Doe's count would be the sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you break down the process a bit.

```
def initials_from(name)
  name.split(" ").map { |name| name[0] }.join("")
end

def is_dup?(first, second)
  first == second
end

def matches?(first, second)
  initials_from(first[:name]) == second[:name] &&
    first[:number] == second[:number]
end

combined_result = a.each_with_object([]) { |first, result|
  # Skip duplicates
  duplicate = b.detect { |b_member| is_dup?(first, b_member) }
  next unless duplicate.nil?

  matching = b.detect { |b_member| matches?(first, b_member) }

  if matching
    combined = first.dup
    combined[:count] = first[:count] + matching[:count]
    result.push(combined)
  else
    result.push(first)
  end
}

combined_result
# [
#   {:name=>"John Doe",     :number=>"555-234-5678", :count=>33},
#   {:name=>"Jane Doe",     :number=>"555-456-1234", :count=>12},
#   {:name=>"Kobie Bryant", :number=>"555-621-9876", :count=>14}
# ]
```

And then, if you really want to modify `a` in-place instead of getting a new array:

```
a.replace(combined_result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do as below :

```
a = [{:name=>"John Doe", :number=>"555-234-5678", :count=>30}, {:name=>"Jane Doe", :number=>"555-456-1234", :count=>12}, {:name=>"Kobie Bryant", :number=>"555-621-9876", :count=>8}, {:name=>"JD", :number=>"555-234-5678", :count=>3}, {:name=>"KB", :number=>"555-621-9876", :count=>6}]

b = [{:name=>"JD", :number=>"555-234-5678", :count=>3}, {:name=>"KB", :number=>"555-621-9876", :count=>6}]

ary = a.group_by do |inner_hash|
  name = inner_hash[:name]
  [/([A-Z])(?:\w+\s+)?([A-Z])/.match(name).captures.join , inner_hash[:number]]
end

array_of_hash = ary.flat_map do |k,v|
  bol = b.select do |hash|
    name = hash[:name]
    [/([A-Z])(?:\w+\s+)?([A-Z])/.match(name).captures.join , hash[:number]] == k
  end.empty?
  unless bol
    count = v.inject(0) { |sum,h1| sum = sum + h1[:count] }
    max_val_string = v.max_by { |h| h[:name].size }[:name]
  end
  next {:name => max_val_string, :number => k.last , :count => count} unless bol
  v
end
array_of_hash
# => [{:name=>"John Doe", :number=>"555-234-5678", :count=>33},
#     {:name=>"Jane Doe", :number=>"555-456-1234", :count=>12},
#     {:name=>"Kobie Bryant", :number=>"555-621-9876", :count=>14}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `[:name, :number]` in `b` is unique (slight modification needed if not):

```
b_index = Hash[b.map { |x| [x.values_at(:name, :number), x[:count]] }]
b_index.default = 0

r = 
  a.reject { |x| 
    b_index.has_key?(x.values_at(:name, :number)) 
  } \
  .map { |x| 
    name, number = x.values_at(:name, :number)
    initials = name.split(/\s+/).map { |y| y[0] }.join 
    x[:count] += b_index[[initials, number]]
    x
  }
```